# Number of integers for which $np(n)$ is a perfect square

Tags: nt.number-theory, partitions

Let $p(n)$ be the partition function. Are $n=1,2,3$ the only cases for which $np(n)$ is a perfect square?

Comment: How far have you looked? $np(n)$ is tabulated out to $n=1000$ at http://oeis.org/A066186/b066186.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested if $np(n)$ is a perfect power for all $n\leq 10^8$, and found no other examples.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Gerry Myerson, I examined OEIS but made a computational error. Thanks @wojowu

According to Magma, there are no values of $n \in (3,10000]$ for which $np(n)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: [636 is not an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+636*PartitionsP(636)), and [neither is 531](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+531*PartitionsP(531)). I have tested up to 4000 and found no examples bigger than 3.

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu, fixed.